# "Type 'OracleConnection' is not defined." error in my ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I have an ASP.NET project which is working fine in my local host. But when I uploaded it to the web server I get this error:

> ### Compilation Error
>
> **Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message:** BC30002: Type 'OracleConnection' is not defined.
>
> **Source Error:**
> `Line 11: Public NotInheritable Class OracleDao`
> `Line 12: Inherits DataAccessObject`
> `Line 13:     Private m_connection As OracleConnection`
> `Line 14:     Private Dim s_connection As ConnectionString`
> `Line 15:     Private aliases As OracleType() = New OracleType() {OracleType.Number,OracleType.Number,OracleType.Char,OracleType.DateTime, _`

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is ASP.NET, not ASP Classic.  You may get more answers if you post it with the correct tags.

Comment: I'm not an ASP programmer but I've used Oracle extensively with .net. I suspect that the Oracle client is not installed on the Web Server or if it is then the ODP bit is not

Comment: @Ciarán you are maybe right because i just installed Pesk on windows 2008 r2 ,this project for my friend how i can install Oracle client ? dose require special license ?

Comment: No, it's a simple download from Oracle though I think you'll need to register first.

Comment: thank u ill try that and ill let u know if its worked

Answer (score 0):

problem caused by overzealous addition of permissions. Make sure the Role Members ‘db_denydatawriter’ and ‘deny_datareader’ are unchecked.

[image]